# How to call another site collection in SharePoint 2010 by jquery?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, javascript, jquery, jsom

We need to get information from another site collection by jquery in Sharepoint 2010.

```
        var subFolderContext = new SP.ClientContext('http://xyz:9999/abc');
        var web = subFolderContext.get_web();
        var oList = web.get_lists().getByTitle("EmployeeDetail");
        var query = SP.CamlQuery.createAllFoldersQuery();
        query.set_folderServerRelativeUrl(folderUrl);
        var items = oList.getItems(query);
        subFolderContext.load(oList); 
        subFolderContext.load(items);
        subFolderContext.executeQueryAsync(function (sender, args) { }
```

However, it's not returning any result.

Comment: Hi, do use has required permissions to execute on other site collection.

Comment: Yes, currently code is executed with site collection administrator access right.

Comment: You cannot make cross-sitecollection calls from javascript client object model in SharePoint 2010. Refer this link - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93653/can-we-access-list-from-other-site-collection-sites-using-javascript-object-mode