# Get the value of one row with the ID in argument

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, web-part

I would like to display through the script editor the Content of one row in a parent site. For each row, I have a unique value, I would like to put it as an argument.
I'm not a JavaScript expert, therefore I tried to adapt some code founded on Internet but doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understood your problem. Please try to include your code snippets and the errors you encountered to help others help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rigth now, I can Display several fields with :

```
clientContext.load(collListItem);
```

and

```
listItemInfo += '<strong>ID: </strong> '  + oListItem.get_id() +
'<strong>ID: </strong> '  + oListItem.get_item('field1') +
'<strong>ID: </strong> '  + oListItem.get_item('field2') +
```

But I also want to display the "Name" of the element, I can do it with :

```
clientContext.load(collListItem, 'Include(DisplayName)');
```

and

```
listItemInfo += '<strong>ID: </strong> '  + oListItem.get_displayName()
```

I didn't find yet how to combine these two Displays...

Answer (score 1):

When using JSOM to query list items, you must include the fields you want to read in your `load` statement.

This would change your line

```
clientContext.load(collListItem);
```

into

```
clientContext.load(collListItem, "Include('Title', 'TaskName')");
```

where `TaskName` is the internal field name.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, it's helped me. This is not correct for me (I already saw this solution before) but I search the documentation of the load function and it should be clientContext.load(this.collListItem);

Comment: Is it possible to reach a list which is in the parent site ? I am trying, context = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl) but no results

Comment: [This link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93653/can-we-access-list-from-other-site-collection-sites-using-javascript-object-mode) should work

Comment: It works it was just long to display because of the amount of data. Thanks for your replies